# how to check whether raw_input is integer, string and date in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to check my user input whether it is integer, string or date.

```
data1 = raw_input("data = ")
    print(data1)

    if isinstance(data1, datetime.datetime.strptime(data1, '%Y-%m-%d')):

        print("date it is")

    elif isinstance(data1, int):

        print("int it is")

    elif isinstance(data1, basestring):
        print("str it is")
```

But it is showing:

```
time data '10' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

Comment: How do you distinguish between the string `'5'` and the int `5`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) will raise `ValueError` if the string does not match the format.
2. [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) always return string object, so [`isinstance(data1, int)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) always is `False` if you don't covert the `data1` to int object before check.
3. I'd suggest use [`try...except`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to catch the `ValueError` like the following code:

   ```
   import datetime

   data1 = raw_input("data = ")
   print(data1)

   try:
       datetime.datetime.strptime(data1, '%Y-%m-%d')

   except ValueError:

       try:
           int(data1)

       except ValueError:
           print("str it is")

       else:
           print("int it is")
   else:
       print("date it is")
   ```

   Demo:

   ```
   kevin@Arch ~> python2 input_check.py 
   data = 2014-01-02
   2014-01-02
   date it is

   kevin@Arch ~> python2 input_check.py 
   data = 12
   12
   int it is

   kevin@Arch ~> python2 input_check.py 
   data = foobar
   foobar
   str it is
   ```

Comment: @Sagar: No problem ;)

Comment: what if i create one function of the above code and pass it as parameter. than its showing error like `datetime.datetime.strptime(dat1, '%Y-%m-%d')
TypeError: must be string, not int`

Answer (score 1):

What Kevin suggested is the correct way to go. However if you sometimes get stuck and need to verify quickly in the middle of coding what is the type of certain variable for example you can use type(). just to get certainty. The final code should have a proper error handling like in Kevin's example.

```
    print type(1)
    print type('words')
    print type(True)

    OR

    user_input = raw_input('>')
    print type(user_input), user_input

    OR

    user_input2 = raw_input('>')
    user_input2 = int(user_input2)
    print type(user_input2), user_input2

    OR

    user_input3 = raw_input('>')
    user_input3 = float(user_input3)
    print type(user_input3), user_input3
```